# Как сделать чтобы при нажатия на текст открывалась ссылка?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно создать текст в Winforms, если человек на него нажимает открывается ссылка.

Заранее
Спасибо.

Comment: вы пытались найти ответ на свой вопрос? https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.2.php

Comment: Я смотрел эту статью до того как написать вопрос. Но у меня возникает ошибка System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Почему бы не конкретизировать заранее сразу в вопросе "пробовал сделать по такой-то статье, вышла такая-то ошибка"? Хотя, впрочем, если вам не особо критично сразу получить ответ или чуть позже...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", url);
```